# Apple Swift - Placing a variable inside arc4random_uniform

Tags: class, variables, swift

Got a rather basic Swift question for you all.

**My goal:** To be able to use a variable (count of items in an array) inside of arc4random.

**Problem:** I don't know how to move "balloonCount" outside of the createBalloons() function.

**Solution?** Define "balloonCount" above currentIndex, that way the program will recognize this variable. (I was told this is the solution, I just unfortunately do not know how to do this.... yet)

Here is my (updated) swift code:

```
//
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var balloonsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!


var balloons:[Balloon] = []

var currentIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(balloons.count)))
```

'ViewController.type' does not have a member named 'balloons'

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.createBalloons()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func nextBalloonBarButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let balloon = balloons[currentIndex]
```

'ViewController' does not have a member named 'currentIndex'

```
    balloonsLabel.text = "\(balloon.number) Balloon"
    backgroundImageView.image = balloon.image

    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
```

'ViewController' does not have a member named 'currentIndex'

```
    if currentIndex > 99 {
```

'ViewController' does not have a member named 'currentIndex'
            currentIndex = 50
        }

```
}


func createBalloons () {
    for var balloonCount = 0; balloonCount <= 99; ++balloonCount{

        var balloon = Balloon()


        //I dont think you need a switch here.
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))

        let balloonName:String = "redBalloon\(randomNumber).jpg"

        balloon.image = UIImage(named: balloonName)
        balloon.number = balloonCount 

        self.balloons.append(balloon)

    }
}

}
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the `count` property built into the `Array<T>` type. Try `self.baloons.count` in your `arc4random()`

Comment: @JMFR - that didn't seem to do the trick. I also tried self.balloonCount.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can assign a function to a variable that uses another instance variable.

I would make currentIndex an Int and then create a seperate getRandomIndex function.  So the code would look something like this:

```
var currentIndex: Int!
func getRandomIndex() -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(balloons.count)))
}

@IBAction func nextBalloonBarButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    currentIndex = getRandomIndex()
    let balloon = balloons[currentIndex]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, not sure if syntax is 100% though. I do not have Xcode on this comp. Let me know if this helped a little. Also if anyone sees anything that seems wrong here please post comment below and I will update my answer.

Try this:

```
var currentIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(balloons.count)))
```

Also I made a few changes here:

```
func createBalloons () {
    for var balloonCount = 0; balloonCount <= 99; ++balloonCount{

        var balloon = Balloon()


    //I dont think you need a switch here.
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))

    let balloonName:String = "redBalloon\(randomNumber).jpg"

    balloon.image = UIImage(named: balloonName)
    balloon.number = balloonCount 

    self.balloons.append(balloon)

    }
}
```

Comment: @Joe did this answer help you out?

Comment: Thank you for lending a hand! Unfortunately it still did not work. I'm getting a few errors. See below!

var currentIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(balloon.count)))

(! Use of unresolved identifier 'balloon')


let balloon = balloons[currentIndex]
currentIndex = currentIndex + 1

^ Both of those lines give me:
'ViewController' does not have a member named 'currentIndex'

Comment: Should be `balloons.count` to match your array.

Comment: @Joe did you find my answer helpful? Let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: @the_pantless_coder - still no luck :( I've edited my initial post with the updated code (that you provided) along with all of the errors i am getting. I feel like it's something very simple i am forgetting/missing, just can't figure out what..