# Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'UInt32'

Tags: ios, swift, casting, swift-array

The goal of the code below is this - get all objects from the parse.com class called `OnlineUsers` and then find a RANDOM number between `0` and `results.count` and then use that object for something.

Issue is that when I try to get the object at position `results[randomNumber]`, I get the error below. I get the same error if I try `results[randomNumberCast]` below.

How can I solve this problem?

```
func findRandomOnlineUser() {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        var user1 = PFUser.currentUser()
        var user2 = PFUser()



        //find user2, i.e. some user who is online right now
        //Showing OnlineUsers only
        let onlineUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "OnlineUsers")
        onlineUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if results!.count > 0 {
                self.mLog.printToLog("launchChatwithRandomUser() -- There are more than zero objects in OnlineUsers")

                //help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770730/apple-swift-placing-a-variable-inside-arc4random-uniform
                let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(results!.count))
                var randomNumberCast = Int(randomNumber)

                if let userObject = results[randomNumberCast] {
                    user2 = userObject["user"] as! PFUser
                } else {
                    //handle the case of 'self.objects' being 'nil'
                }

    } else {
        //TODO: Show a prompt that user is not logged in and then take user to Login Screen
    }


}
```

Error Message:

[image: Screenshot showing the error message]

Comment: Try this. if let userObject = results![randomNumberCast]. Use ! operator results!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the fact that `results` seems to be an optional array: `[AnyObject]?`.
Therefore, if you want to access one of its values via a subscript, you have to unwrap the array first:

```
if let userObject: AnyObject = results?[randomNumberCast]
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. ios noob trying to understand this unwrapping thing.

Comment: I think i spoke too soon, I am seeing this error when i build. Any idea?: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hg88557wqut10nd/Screenshot%202015-05-18%2000.32.49.png?dl=0

Comment: check my answer properly...that is not what i suggested